# Access EventHandler Between Two Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I wants to access Form1's EventHandler In Form2

**Form1 EventHandler  is**:-

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```

How to achieve it?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing something wrong.

If you want to expose functionality, you should create a public method/function to do so. You can call this from your event handler *and* from your other form.

Comment: @Oded, I think You are right, if i modify the "private" modifier to "Public" than how to i call it in form2?. Please provide some example.

Comment: @mahesh - You should not be exposing event handler this way. If you use a public method, you just need a reference to the object it is defined on and call it.

Comment: Would you please explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: @A_Nablsi - did you mean to comment on the question, rather than my answer?

Comment: @Oded, reference means by declaring "global static object" and put the public method reference to it.

Comment: @mahesh - No, a reference means having a variable that points to the object in question. Nothing to do with "global" or "static".

Comment: @mahesh, Oded says like my answer :D

Comment: @Oded, I am confuse can you give me simple example?

Comment: @SaeedAlg - not really. Event handlers should not be public.

Comment: @mahesh - how does Form2 know anything about Form1 in your code?

Comment: @Oded, where is public in my Event handler? my event is public not its handler.

Comment: @Oded - Yes, sure the question. Sorry I should have commented on the question rather than your answer I was reading the comments on your answer when I added my comment.

Comment: @Oded, I have sum/calculating code  between DGV's Columns on above method on Form1 and I wants to access it completely from form2. and from form2 again I have to replace it in form1 at form_load eventhandler/method.

Comment: @Oded, I think you are against of access eventhandler between forms, any reason?. it may possible that what you saw before that i have not seen it yet. can you tell me any disadvantages is there to access eventhandler?.

Comment: @Oded I am welcome your idea. but i personally feel that you must have to take part in comment discussion it will increase more and more knowledge. as well as it will help to new comer.

Comment: @mahesh - when I feel I don't have anything to add to a discussion, I don't add to it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer updated by your question in comment, I didn't checked that it works fine may be there is a bug with it:
It's useful when you have a similar event, Also you can pass different EventArgs, easiest way is to have a different Property which determines each form and add event in their `set` methods but bellow is general

```
public abstract class FormBase : Form
{
    public virtual event EventHandler MyEventHandler;
}

public class Form3 : FormBase
{
    public override event EventHandler MyEventHandler;
    Form2 instance;
    public Form3()
    {
        instance = Form2.Instance;
        instance[this.GetType().ToString()] = this;
        // or 
        //instance["Form3"] = this;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // todo
        if (MyEventHandler != null)
            MyEventHandler(this, e);
    }
}

public class Form2
{
    Dictionary<string, FormBase> dic = new Dictionary<string,FormBase>();

    public FormBase this[string index]
    {
        get 
        { 
            FormBase retVal = null;
            if (dic.TryGetValue(index, out retVal))
                return retVal;
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            FormBase retVal = null;

            if (value == null)
                return;

            if (dic.TryGetValue(index, out retVal))
            {
                try
                {
                    value.MyEventHandler -= MyEventHandler1;
                }
                catch
                { 
                }

                retVal = value;

                retVal.MyEventHandler += MyEventHandler1;
                return;
            }

            value.MyEventHandler += MyEventHandler1;

            dic.Add(index, value);
        }
    }

    private static Form2 instance;
    public static Form2 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            { 
                instance = new Form2();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private Form2()
    {
    }

    private void MyEventHandler1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: @Saeed, Can you tell me if more than two forms have to access than your code will works or not?

Comment: @mahesh, Yes, they work fine, If you have an instance of Form1, you can use its event anywhere, you can copy and past above code and multiple time use it, this is a basic of event routing see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx, It's for WPF also it can be learned for Win forms

Comment: @SaeedAlg, You are right that multiple instances will do for that but here is in your code i see that you have create two object of form1. one is out of form2 constructure and other is in form2 constructure.

Comment: ... if suppose I have form3 and same condition is above. I mean if i also wants to access form3's event in form2 than how can do it with your same code.

Comment: @mahesh, you should pass form3 to form2 to have its event, So you can do 2 thing, first pass form3 to form2 with some method and same thing for form1, I'll edit my code to show you, At last, I have just `1` Form1 in Form2

Comment: @SaeedAlg, I appreciate your efforts but as far my point of view Mr.oded suggestion is very true that doesn't mean that your efforts is useless. i am appreciate your new idea and welcome you. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the access modifier to public instead of private.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to parse the eventhandler on `Form1` to `Form2`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataGridViewCellEventHandler dataGridViewCellEventHandler = new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);
        this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += dataGridViewCellEventHandler;

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.CellEndEdit += dataGridViewCellEventHandler;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event DataGridViewCellEventHandler CellEndEdit
    {
        add { dataGridViewOnForm2.CellEndEdit += value; }
        remove { dataGridViewOnForm2.CellEndEdit -= value; }
    }
}
```

This does however require that `Form1` has access to `Form2`

Comment: There is compile error, "The name datagridview1 does not exists in the current context". I think form1 datagridview eventhandler not access in your case.

Comment: @mahesh, I have not shown all of the code. I have added another DataGridView on Form2 (dataGridViewOnForm2). My geuss was that you had a DataGridView on both Form1 and Form2 and wanted to reuse the EventHandler?

Comment: Oh! no I have datagridview on form1 only. which events i have to utilise or access in form2. and again replace it in form1 at form1_load Event.